# unable to import dependencies in kotlin multiplatform project

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl, kotlin-native

Intellij Version: 2019.3

I am new to Kotlin-native development and would greatly appreciate any help I get. I created a Kotlin native/gradle project and I added the okhttp dependency to the project and I did not run into any issues in doing so.

But I am not able to import the okhttp library into the source. I keep getting "Unresolved reference: okhttp".

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello! I'm not sure if it's possible at all, as the `okhttp` seems to be JVM-only library. I found mention of `okio` going MPP(see [here](https://square.github.io/okio/changelog/#version-230)). But, it has to use different Maven coordinates, as mentioned in the changelog.

Comment: is there any alternative to okhttp; http client support for Kotlin-Natvie?

Comment: Ktor has a client with Multiplatform support. https://ktor.io/clients/http-client/multiplatform.html